# How can I make an image map using javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, imagemap

I seem to be stuck on an issue to make an image map using javascript Objects.  The goal is to get this code to return a color.  I'm working on my own text editor plugin using js objects and I got the bold, underline, font size to work, but I can't seem to get around the ForeColor option.  This is the code for the forecolor selector I have so far.  If you have a better solution, pls suggested.  thanks.

```
$.fn.JStextEditor = function(options){

    // extend the option with the default ones
    var settings = $.extend({
      coords : ["7,36,21,51","29,36,43,50","51,36,65,51"]
                  //with some other options..
    },options);


        //Font Selector
        var ForeColorPick = $("<img/>",{
        id  : "forecolorPicker",
        src : "images/colorPallette.png",
        usemap : "#colorPicker",
        css : {
                   display : "none",
                   "float" : "left",
                   width   : "185px",
                   height  : "214px",
                   border  : "none"
               },
            data : {
              commandName : "foreColor"
            },
            click : execCommand

          }).appendTo(SomeDiv );





        var colorMap = $("<map/>",{
            "name" : "colorPicker"              
          }).appendTo(buttonPane ); 




        $.each(settings.coords,function(i,v){
            $("<area/>",{
              value   : v,
              shape : "rect",
              css : {
                   cursor  : "pointer"
               },
              "coords" : v
            }).appendTo(colorMap );

          });

};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a plugin like this?

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?what.html

This helped me immensely on a previous project.

Comment: I have but none of them include a checkbox option.  That's why I'm doing my own.  Got everything working nicely except the Forecolor option.